# Готовый плагин для обрезки картинки

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, javascript, php

Подскажите, кто-нибудь видел готовый JQuery плагин для обрезки и резайза картинки
(подобный реализован вконтакте):

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Конечно есть](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/jquery-image-crop-plugin-jcrop/)

[Демо](http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php)

http://code.google.com/p/jcrop/

[А тут файл с полным набором всех кодов, включая php страничку.](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop_Download.html)

Comment: Огромное спасибо. То что нужно!

Answer (score 0):

Тема хорошая, а какой лучший, тот что и на мобилах работает, я очень долго мутил с **Croppie**, работает но много нюансов, вообщем не рекомендую если у вас дизайн адаптивный, либо делать так чтобы не был блок с фото адаптивным. Ибо у скрипта идет фиксированные контейнера куда идет загрузка фото и если сужать экран чтобы блок сузился, то фото уходят за пространство. и если вы захотите выбрать фото полностью, то не сможете это сделать. Так что при адаптации походу надо у контейнера через js менять разрешения контейнера.