# Помогите реализовать обрезку картинки в PHP

Tags: gd, php

Есть форма, через которую люди загружают на сайт изображения. Скрипт проверяет - картинка это или нет, если картинка, то сохраняет и выводит в браузер. Как сделать так, чтобы при загрузке через форму картинка обрезалась до размеров 100 на 100 пикселей? Пока, что в Гугле ничего рабочего не нашел.

Вот собственно код PHP:

```
if(isset($_FILES['filename']['name']))
    {
        $name = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
        $typeok = TRUE; ####
        #$name = strtolower(ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9.]", "", $name); //Скрипт перестает работать, если раскомментировать эту строчку((
        switch($_FILES['filename']['type'])
        {
            case 'image/jpeg': $ext = 'jpg'; break;
            case 'image/pjpeg': $ext = 'jpg'; break;
            case 'image/gif': $ext = 'gif'; break;
            case 'image/png': $ext = 'png'; break;
            case 'image/tiff': $ext = 'tif'; break;
            default: $typeok = FALSE; break;
        }
        if($ext)
        {
            $n = strtolower("$name");
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "images/users/$n");
            echo("<div class=\"alert alert-success\">");
            echo("<p>Загружено изображение $name под именем $n: </p><br>");
            echo("<img src='images/users/$n'>");
            echo("</div>");
        }
        else
        {
            echo("<div class=\"alert alert-error\">");
            echo ("<p>'$name' - неприемлимый файл изображения</p>");
            echo("</div>");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo("<div class=\"alert alert-error\">");
        echo ("<p>Загрузки изображения не произошло!</p>");
        echo("</div>");
    }
```

Comment: $name = strtolower(ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9.]", "", $name);

          ----------
          $name = strtolower(ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9.]", "", $name));

Comment: Порядок действий на примере JPEG:

imagecreatetruecolor, imagecreatefromjpeg, imagecopyresampled, imagejpeg

Создаёшь пустое изображение размерами 100x100, грузишь существующее, копируешь нужную часть изображения в пустое, сохраняешь.

Comment: Спасибо, за подсказки, сейчас попробую осуществить!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот интересный плагин:
[обрезка картинки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/41690/%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8)

Answer (score 3):

Можно как то так:

```
$crop_x = ...;
$crop_y = ...;
$crop_width = ...;
$crop_height = ...;
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($crop_width, $crop_height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg(...);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, $crop_x, $crop_y, $crop_width, $crop_height, $crop_width, $crop_height);
$img_data = tempnam("/tmp","crop");
//сохраняем тут по имени $img_data
imagejpeg($image_p, $img_data);
imagedestroy($image_p);
imagedestroy($image);
unlink($img_data);
```