# Обрезка изображений

Tags: php, изображения

У кого-нибудь есть функция для создания превью изображения? Но так, чтоб оно обрезалось (как вконтакте), т.е. изображение допустим `560х400` уменьшалось и потом обрезалось до `100х100`.

Comment: imagecreatefromjpeg,
imagecreatefrompng,

Comment: По моему вопрос уже где-то был.

Answer (score 2):

- [Обработка изображений на php](http://goo.gl/28inv)
- [Создание эскизов на php](http://goo.gl/8gTGJ)

Answer (score 0):

Решение с использованием `convert`:

```
convert /path/original/file.jpg -colors 8 -resize 100x100^ -gravity Center -crop 100x100+0+0 +repage /path/output/file.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Уже был вопрос на эту тему: [Помогите реализовать обрезку картинки в PHP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/113158/gd-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-php).